# How do I retrieve the interface of the constants from a generic enum type?

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums

I'm designign an argument of a method, for a class that has to handle generic enumerations (I mean, the class could be part of a library, and the user will provide that class method with a user-defined enumeration, whose specific type is not known to the class being designed - let's call this class the "library class").

I want to syntactically constrain that argument type as much as possible so that only correct types will be allowed.

My requirements are that the type must be an enumeration that implements a specific interface, `EnumKind`:

```
public interface EnumKind {

    String getText();

}
```

So far I have been able to write this type:

```
Class<? extends Enum<? extends EnumKind>> t;
```

With that declaration, and having these:

```
public enum MyEnumKind implements EnumKind {

    // ...

    public String getText() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}

public class MyClassKind implements EnumKind {

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}

public enum MyEnum {

}
```

Only `t = MyEnumKind.class` is correct, other assignments (like `t = MyClassKind.class`) are rejected from the compiler, which is the behaviour I want.

Now, in the body of my method I can succesfully do:

```
Enum<? extends EnumKind>[] tt = t.getEnumConstants();
```

But I haven't found a way to directly retrieve the `EnumKind`s, to get access to each enumeration constant `getText()` method.

How do I get an array of `EnumKind` elements without explicit casting? Is that type declaration the best I can write, or can I improve it?
If explicit casting can't be avoided, can I be 100% safe that the type declaration will avoid any possibility of any `ClassCastException` (or any similar exception) being thrown?

---

**EDIT**

---

I'll elaborate a bit more, since I'm hitting another road block.

The `EnumKind` interface requires the enumeration to associate a string to a each enum constant, i.e.:

```
public enum MyEnumKind implements EnumKind {

    A("#A#"),
    B("#B#"),
    C("#C#");

    private String text;

    private Token(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Next, I want to retrieve the enum constant that corresponds to a specific string, e.g.

```
? enumValue = getValueFor("#A#");
```

`enumValue` (what should be its type?) should represent `MyEnumKind.A` here, and there's no need to know the actual value, since `enumValue` will be passed to another method.

And I've designed my library class like this (after @JoopEggen answer):

```
public class EnumManager<T extends Enum<?> & EnumKind> {

    private Class<T> en;

    public EnumManager(Class<T> en) {
        this.en = en;
    }

   protected ? getValueFor(String s) {
        for(EnumKind ek : en.getEnumConstants()) {
            if(s.equals(ek.getText())) {
                // I found the enum constant I need... and now?
                return ? ;
            }
        }

    }

    //...
```

How should I complete that code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe since `Number[]` is a superclass to `Integer[]` (contrary to `List<Number>` **not** being a superclass of `List<Integer>`).

So if the declared component type of `tt` (the declared type of the elements of `tt`) implements `EnumKind`, an array of such elements extends `EnumKind[]` therefore this is safe:

```
EnumKind[] tt = (EnumKind[]) t.getEnumConstants(); // Casting to superclass: OK
```

You get no warnings because this is safe and you will never get `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm investigating Joop's answer to see if I can simplify the code.

Comment: I've added an explanation about what I want to do. Can you give it a look please?

Comment: "if the elements of `tt` implement `EnumKind`, an array of such elements extends `EnumKind[]`" That's not true. `EnumKind[] tt = (EnumKind[])new Object[]{ MyEnumKind.A };` will fail, even though all the elements implement `EnumKind`.

Comment: Yeah, well what I meant was the declared component type of the array. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

To use `.getText`  T must "extend" EnumKind too. The Enum wrapper does not provide this.

```
public static class MyC<T extends Enum<?> & EnumKind> {
    public void f(T t) {
        System.out.println("-> " + t.getText());
    }
}
```

Above you see `extends CLASS & INTERFACE`. The extra bound must be to an interface.

---

***After question edit:***

```
protected T getValueFor(String s) {
    for (T t : en.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (s.equals(ek.getText())) {
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe better with a static HashMap.

*I am afraid, that the entire code might become overdesigned. It would be better to follow a simple design, with too many artifacts.*

You want something like an AbstractEnum, abstracting from

```
public enum EnumABC {
    A("a"), B("b"), C("c");

    private static final Map<String, EnumABC> textToEnum = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (EnumABC value : values()) {
            EnumABC oldValue = textToEnum.put(value.text, value);
            if (oldValue != null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        String.format("Enum %s: same value %s for %s and %s",
                                value.getClass().getName(),
                                value.text,
                                oldValue,
                                value));
            }
        }
    }

    public static EnumABC fromText(String text) {
        EnumABC value = textToEnum.get(text);
        return value;
    }

    private final String text;

    private EnumABC(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Good luck.

***Simpler:***

```
@Override
public String getText() {
    String s = toString();
    return "#" + s.replace('_', ' ') + "#";
}
```

Comment: Uhm... if I understand you, you're suggesting to move the generic type declaration to the class declaration instead of using a particular argument type, is that right?

Comment: No, that was just my test in order to use getText. (I was not entirely sure about your usage of `t`.) Wanted to mention the generics' `&`.

Comment: I've added an explanation about what I want to do. Can you give it a look please?

Answer (score 0):

How about a generic method:

```
static <T extends Enum<T> & EnumKind> T helper(Class<T> t, String s) {
    EnumKind[] tt = t.getEnumConstants();
    // do what you need to do here
}
```

Comment: I need to return the actual enum constant, found by comparing a string with the return of `getText()`. In the snippet you wrote, I can't return, e.g., `tt[0]`, I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from TokenEnum to T". But you gave me an hint, and I replaced `for(EnumKind ek : en.getEnumConstants())` with `for(T ek : en.getEnumConstants())` in my code above: inside the loop I can do `ek.getText()` and I can return `ek`.